# How to update Multiple rows in PostgreSQL with other fields of same table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

I have table which consist of 35,000 records in which half of the rows have name as null value
If the field has null value, i want to update the field with the value of username.

Can anyone help me with this ?

This is sample table

```
name    | username    | idnumber    | type
----------------------------------------------
--      | jack        | 1         | A
Mark    | Mark        | 2         | B
--      | dev         | 3         | A
```

**After update i want it to look like this**

```
name    | username    | idnumber    | type
----------------------------------------------
jack    | jack        | 1         | A
Mark    | Mark        | 2         | B
dev     | dev         | 3         | A
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want:

```
update t
    set name = username
    where name is null;
```

Note that `--` is not a typical representation of `NULL` values.  You might consider `<null>` for instance.

Comment: Thanks... It Worked